# Remove an event listener for arrow function with parameters

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, how can I remove an event listener that was added using an arrow function with parameters?

```js
class myClass {

    animateIn(callback) {

        // Add an event listener for the end of the animation
        this.myDomElement.addEventListener(
            'animationend',
            (e) => this.onAnimateInAnimationEnd(e, callback)
        );
    }

    onAnimateInAnimationEnd = (e, callback) => {

         // Remove the event listener for the end of the animation
        this.myDomElement.removeEventListener(
            'animationend',
            (e) => this.onAnimateInAnimationEnd(e, callback)
        );
    }
}
```

I understand that using `this.onAnimateInAnimationEnd` instead of `(e) => this.onAnimateInAnimationEnd(e, callback)` will remove the event listener correctly. However, that does not allow me to access the `callback` parameter inside `onAnimateInAnimationEnd`.

How do I make it work with both `e`, which is related to the event I am listening to, and `callback`, which is not related to that event?

Comment: create a function (it can be an arrow function - actually, scratch that, it can't) and use that ... because `() => {}` `!==` `() => {}`

Comment: But how do I make it work with both `e`, which is related to the event I am listening to, and `callback`, which is not related to that event?

Comment: Perhaps like this https://pastebin.com/A3Wa1fPh